# User account in Microsoft IIS 8.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm very new to Microsoft IIS. I want to hold an FTP site on Windows Server 2012 R2.
I googled and found out there's few authoorizaing method I can use. But I don't know which kind of method I should use. ASP.NET, .NET or IIS manager?

My requirements:

1. User is able to change password by himself
2. Can also be easily used in WebDAV if I try to setup one

Thanks very much if anyone can tell me a way to do this.

Comment: "IIS Manager" is not an authentication scheme.  ASP.NET is an HTTP technology, not an FTP technology.  FTP and WebDav are mutually exclusive.

Comment: download, install and configure [Filezilla Server](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) ... much easier and works amazingly well. That's what I do on my WinServer 2012R2!

Comment: But I can see ASPNETAuth in FTP authorizing. Any ideas?
I just finish config the ftp server on IIS. But then my lab members told me it is very weird that they can't key their password by themselves.

Comment: @balexandre I'm not sure. When I bought this server, the reseller tell me using Filezilla Server isn't a good idea since I acually have a server license.

Comment: @KKyang I use it in production of a very big website, we have license for hardware and software, but still use Filezilla Server. IIS is only to host our websites (23 sites actually).

Comment: @balexandre So you prefer to use FileZilla as FTP and use IIS to host websites?

Comment: @KKyang Yes, that's our setup. Create a folder `FTProot` and add it to Filezilla, per each folder, I create an IIS Website and it's own AppPool. Then it's easy to update (though I setup IIS to use WebDeploy, as we use Visual Studio)